# How to write query to search particular string in a table which has more column fields in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I would like to know how to write sql query to search string in all columns in a table.
i.e in single where condition

I have column1, column2,... column50 fields in a table

Right now am using query like

`select * from tblist where column1 like '%searchstr%'OR column2 like '%searchstr%' OR` ....it goes on

Is there anyway to write sql query to search string in all columns

Comment: you could save some of the grunt work by using the metadata table

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your exact query as given, we can try using `IN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tblist
WHERE 'searchstr' IN (column1, column2, ...);
```

If you really need to use `LIKE` here, then there is no real shortcut available.

Answer (score 0):

you could save on the grunt work by using the metadata tables to generate your query and then run it. Eg:

```
select concat('%searchstr% like ',COLUMN_NAME,' OR ')
  from information_schema.columns t
where table_name='t' /*change to the table name*/
```